# Model Driven Form Dropdown not working. Not getting value

Tags: angular, forms, validation, select, dropdown

I have a form, which I'm trying to validate through `FormBuilder`, and everything seems to work but the dropdowns. The value from the `option` is not being reflected in the component class. For simplicity I'll just post the dropdown parts.

```
this.form = formBuilder.group({
  'type': [null, Validators.required]
});
```

This is just to check whether form changes trigger the event. All the input boxes work fine, it's just the dropdowns that are not triggering it.

```
this.form.valueChanges
  .map((value) => {
    console.log(value);    //Log form changes
    return value;
  })
  .filter((value) => this.form.valid)
  .subscribe((value) => {
    console.log("Model Driven Form valid value: vm = ", JSON.stringify(value));
  });
```

And the html part

```
<select formControlName="type" class="validate">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
    <option value="restaurant">Restaurant</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="cafe">Cafe</option>
</select>
```

If I `console.log()` the form controls after selecting some option in the `type` dropdown, I can see that value is `null`.

Comment: You are now trying to bind variables to your select options, I guess you don't have for example a variable named `restaurant`, but it should instead be `value="restaurant"`

Comment: Thanks, that was what I had before, but it does not work either (I've tried again)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** You can't use `filter` on a rxjs `map`,

```
this.form.valueChanges
.map((value) => {
    console.log(value);    //Log form changes
    return value;
 })
 .subscribe((value) => {
    console.log("Model Driven Form valid value: vm = ", JSON.stringify(value));
 });
```

### [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/form-value-changes-49392097)

---

```
<select formControlName="type" class="validate">
    <option [value]="" disabled selected>Type</option>
    <option [value]="restaurant">Restaurant</option>
    <option [value]="bar">Bar</option>
    <option [value]="cafe">Cafe</option>
</select>
```

should be

```
<select formControlName="type" class="validate">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Type</option>
    <option value="restaurant">Restaurant</option>
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
    <option value="cafe">Cafe</option>
</select>
```

When you say `[value]`, Angular expects a **variable** name, so in the first case when you say 
`[value]="restraunt"` Angular checks for a variable named `restraunt`.

Instead when you specify value as a normal html attribute `value="restraunt"`, you are passing the **string** `restraunt` as the value.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried that before already and it does not work either

Comment: Thank you very much for this!
After 1 hour of trying everything I have realized that the problem is with the CSS framework I am using, which is `Materialize CSS`. If I disable it the dropdowns just work. It must have something to do with its javascript code or something. I don't know how to fix it though